# Why the set of maximal ideal of a domain with jacobson radical zero is infinite?

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain, noetherian, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian domain (is not a field) with $\operatorname{Jac}(R)=(0)$. Why the set of maximal ideal of $R$ is infinite?

Comment: The noetherian condition is not needed at all as the solution demonstrates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were only finitely many maximal ideals $m_1,\ldots,m_n$ then pick non-zero $x_i\in m_i$ and you will find $\prod x_i\in Jac(R)=\bigcap m_i$. But certainly in a domain this product is not zero, so we have found a non-zero element in the Jacobson radical.